# React Mobx does not update view after store change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, mobx

I am just starting to use Mobx. I like Mobx and it worked for most part of my project. However, I just cannot get seemingly simple stuff to work.
After I change requirement in the SelectField, I set the new value to store.selectedRequirement in the onChange event. The onChange event was called successully and store value was updated. However, the SelectField view never updated and it still pointed to the old item. I cannot figure out the cause.

```
@observer
export default class OpenDialog extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }   

    static contextTypes = {
        router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired       
    }

    handleClose = () => {
        this.props.store.openDialog = false;
    }

    componentWillMount = () => {
        const { store } = this.props;
        if(store.selectedRequirement === null)
            store.selectedRequirement = store.requirements[0];
    }

    render = () => {

        const { store } = this.props;

        const actions = [
              <RaisedButton
                label="Cancel"
                style={{marginRight: 16}}
                primary={true}
                onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
              />,
            ];

        const docItemsJSX = store.requirements
            .map((requirement) => {
                return (
                    <MenuItem   
                        key={'requirement-' + requirement.docId}
                        value={requirement}
                        primaryText={requirement.title + ' - ' + requirement.version}>
                    </MenuItem> 
                )                   
            }); 

        return (
            <Dialog
                    title="Open Requirements Document"
                    actions={actions}
                    modal={true}
                    open={store.openDialog}
                >

                <SelectField
                    style={{width: 300}}
                    floatingLabelText="Documents"
                    floatingLabelFixed={true}
                    value={store.selectedRequirement}
                    onChange={(event, index, value) => { 
                        store.selectedRequirement = value;
                    }}
                >
                    {docItemsJSX}
                </SelectField>

            </Dialog>       
        );
    }
}
```

in the AppStore file, i have

```
@observable requirements = [{
    docId: 1,
    title: "Requirements1",
    version: "1.0",
    lastModifiedBy: "abc",
    lastModifiedDate: "11/11/2016",
    publishDate: "11/12/2016"
}, {
    docId: 2,
    title: "Requirements2",
    version: "1.0",
    lastModifiedBy: "def",
    lastModifiedDate: "11/13/2016",
    publishDate: "11/16/2016"
}];

@observable selectedRequirement = null;
@observable openDialog = false;
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.